# ¿Cómo mostrar resultados en una caja al dar clic? ejemplo Suma de dos números

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código, me gustaría ingresar dos valores y a partir de éstos realizar la suma, pero que ésta quede dentro de la caja y no como una alerta.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Documento sin título</title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function valor() {
            var n1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
            var n2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;
            var resultado = (parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2));

            document.getElementById("resultado").val = resultado
        }

    </script>

    <body>
        <input name="n1" type="text" id="n1" size="4" maxlength="5" />
        <input name="n1" type="text" id="n2" size="4" maxlength="5" />
        <input name="suma" type="button" onClick="valor()" value="suma" />
        <input type="text" id="resultado"></input>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: function valor()
{
                var n1= document.getElementById("n1").value;

                var n2= document.getElementById("n2").value;

                var resultado= (parseInt(n1)+parseInt(n2));

               

               document.getElementById("resultado").val=resultado     

}

</script>
<body>
<input name="n1" type="text" id="n1" size="4" maxlength="5" />
<input name="n1" type="text" id="n2" size="4" maxlength="5" />
<input name="suma" type="button" onClick="valor()" value="suma" />
<input type="text" id="resultado"></input>
</body>

</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo hay que cambiar `.val` por `.value`.

```js
function valor() {
    var n1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
    var n2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;
    var resultado = parseInt(n1, 10) + parseInt(n2, 10);
    document.getElementById("resultado").value = resultado;
}
```

```html
<input name="n1" type="text" id="n1" size="4" maxlength="5" />
<input name="n1" type="text" id="n2" size="4" maxlength="5" />
<input name="suma" type="button" onClick="valor()" value="suma" />
<input type="text" id="resultado" />
```

**Nota:** Además, en `parseInt()` se debería poner siempre la base (10).
Por ejemplo, `parseInt(n1, 10)`.

Comment: Yo no uso nunca el parseInt, lo que hago para convertir cadenas a números es multiplicarlos por 1, quedaría así `n1*1+n2*1`.

Comment: @ArtEze Es una opción, y en este caso prefiero usar `parseInt()`. `n1*1` actúa similar a `parseFloat()` en vez de `parseInt()`. Para ver las diferencias en comportamiento, **[ver esta tabla](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17106702/5290909)**. Y estoy manteniendo el código que utilizó el autor, sólo corrigiendo los errores.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y el consejo